# Decryption function in PHP returning a value of 1 (What am I doing wrong?)

Tags: php, encryption

This is the method

```
public function _PRZ_decrypt_data($_salt, $_input)
{   
    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $_salt, $_input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $this->_PRZ_get_iv()));
}
```

I am calling it as one of my parameters as follows

```
$this->_PRZ_decrypt_data($salt, base64_decode($code))
```

It seems to be returning a 1 when a properly endoded value is decoded via the function.

Comment: Encryption, decryption... which is it?

Comment: Can you please provide test data for $_salt and $_input, and explain what is returned by $this->_PRZ_get_iv()?

Answer (score 0):

Break the function calls into a single action per line, and output the inputs, and result of each step. Make sure that you are passing appropriate values in, and get sensible outputs. As the saying goes - [GIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_In,_Garbage_Out). That will tell you where the bad data is coming from. Guessing does not.

Then, look at the [manual page on `mcrypt_decrypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) to see examples of use.